# Custom Display Form with Custom Workflow button

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have created a new custom list form that will show 4 fields on the page from a Custom List called "Shipment". I have added Form Action button that I would like to run a custom action that is set inside of a Workflow. Currently, the form displays the fields for "Manifest Number", "Pickup Location", "Delivery Location", & "Scheduled Pickup Time". When the user clicks the Form Action button, what I want the Workflow to do is go to the ID field of the displayed content in the Form and change the value of the "Picked Up" column from No to Yes. The problem I am having is passing the ID of the displayed information from the Form to the Workflow as a variable. I can get the "Picked Up" column to update if I specify the value in the "Update List Item" window under the "Find the List Item" section, but I cannot figure out how to do this dynamically from the Form

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hidden field to store the ID in the custom list form. Copy the line that displays "Manifest Number" and change it to point to the ID field. And the change the variable name to ff6 or something like that (given you already only have 5 fields). Now when you open the custom action workflow in SPD the ID field should be available for your apply as a filter.

Hope this helps.